# Can I detect which types, when used as a base class, potentially overlap their derived class

Tags: c++, abi, base-class

Consider the following class:

```cpp
class intchar {
    int x;
    char y;
};
```

It has size 8 on all major compilers on x86.

Consider now the a derived class:

```cpp
struct derived : intchar {
    char z;
};
```

On gcc and clang for Linux<sup>1</sup>, this class *also* has size 8, despite being non-empty and deriving from a size 8 base class. So the storage for `derived::z` overlaps the `base` object: `z` is stored in the padding of `base`.

This doesn't occur in other scenarios. E.g. if I change `intchar` to `struct` rather than `class`, then `derived` as size 12: there is no overlap.

Is there any condition or trait I can check *on the base class*, which would rule out overlap? In this specific example `std::is_aggregate` works, but I don't know of any reason why that should be the case or if it would fail in another example.

---

<sup>1</sup> Oddly icc is inconsistent here, reporting the size of `derived` as 12, so I guess it is not C++ ABI compatible with clang or gcc.

Comment: Since changing the type of `z` will change the outcome (e.g. to `int`), this can't logically be checked on the base class. Also, `struct` and `class` are identical except that in a `struct`, everything is public by default; if you added `public:` to `class intchar`, you would get the same effect. Also, storage never overlaps - it is just that the alignment of the base and derived class are identical. `z` is not stored in the padding of `base`, as that byte ceases to be padding.

Comment: If a base class [has unique object representations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/has_unique_object_representations) then you can rule-out overlapping.

Comment: @Erlkoenig - right, but a conservative check is fine: i.e., identifying cases where based on the properties of the base class, it won't overlap. Storage overlaps here: the size of base is 8, and the size of (non-empty) derived is 8, so there is overlap. The standard even calls this case _(potential) overlap_. About "ceases to be padding" - sure, that's just semantics. If you want be to totally explicit I guess it should be "`z` is stored where there was be padding in a complete object of type `base`", but I think everyone knows what I mean with the short form.

Answer (score 2):

If there can be overlapping, it should happen for your test case with only that one `char` so you could write a type trait like this:

```cpp
template<class Base>
struct can_overlap {
    private:
        struct helper : Base {
            char a;
        };
    public:
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(Base) == sizeof(helper);
};

template<class B>
static constexpr bool can_overlap_v = can_overlap<B>::value;

static_assert(can_overlap_v<intchar>);
```

The only possible problem I see is that the type of inheritance (private vs public vs protected) makes a difference, but that is easy to check with some more helper structs and then you take an or over the different possibilities.